# anaconda3/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by ssh)

Tags: python, git, ssh, anaconda, libcrypto

I ran into the problem while trying to use git push

Below are some information I get. Please let me know if I can provide more information.

```
$ git push origin master

ssh: /home/user/anaconda3/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by ssh)
ssh: /home/user/anaconda3/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by ssh)
Permission denied (publickey).
fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

Please make sure you have the correct access rights
and the repository exists.
```

---

```
$ ldd /usr/bin/openssl

/usr/bin/openssl: /home/user/anaconda3/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/openssl)
/usr/bin/openssl: /home/user/anaconda3/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/openssl)
/usr/bin/openssl: /home/user/anaconda3/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/openssl)
/usr/bin/openssl: /home/user/anaconda3/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/openssl)
/usr/bin/openssl: /home/user/anaconda3/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/openssl)
/usr/bin/openssl: /home/user/anaconda3/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/openssl)
/usr/bin/openssl: /home/user/anaconda3/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by /usr/bin/openssl)
    linux-vdso.so.1 =>  (0x00007ffcbcff9000)
    libssl.so.1.0.0 => /home/user/anaconda3/lib/libssl.so.1.0.0 (0x00007ff3ea9ca000)
    libcrypto.so.1.0.0 => /home/user/anaconda3/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 (0x00007ff3ea593000)
    libc.so.6 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0x00007ff3ea1ae000)
    libdl.so.2 => /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0x00007ff3e9faa000)
    /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2 (0x0000556db91a8000)
```

---

```
$ssh --version

ssh: /home/user/anaconda3/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by ssh)ssh: /home/user/anaconda3/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0: no version information available (required by ssh)
unknown option -- -
usage: ssh [-1246AaCfGgKkMNnqsTtVvXxYy] [-b bind_address] [-c cipher_spec]
           [-D [bind_address:]port] [-E log_file] [-e escape_char]
           [-F configfile] [-I pkcs11] [-i identity_file] [-L address]
           [-l login_name] [-m mac_spec] [-O ctl_cmd] [-o option] [-p port]
           [-Q query_option] [-R address] [-S ctl_path] [-W host:port]
           [-w local_tun[:remote_tun]] [user@]hostname [command]
```

---

```
$ locate libcrypto.so

/home/user/anaconda3/lib/libcrypto.so
/home/user/anaconda3/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
/home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/openssl-1.0.2k-1/lib/libcrypto.so
/home/user/anaconda3/pkgs/openssl-1.0.2k-1/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
/snap/core/2312/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
/snap/core/2381/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
/snap/core/2462/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
/snap/electronic-wechat/7/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so.1.0.0
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcrypto.so
```

It seems that there are two libcrypto.so and libcrypto.so.1.0.0 under my anaconda3 distribution. I wonder it might be the cause but don't know how to resolve it. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Source `deactivate` before `git push origin master`.

Comment: @alvits Hi， I did not use virtualenv in this project.

Comment: `anaconda3` is `Continuum Analytics, Inc.`s version of python which is cunnigly similar to `virtualenv`. If you never sourced `activate` then you can modify your `.bashrc` or `.bash_profile` or whatever `.profile` your shell use to remove the path from `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`.

Comment: Hi, it works. Thank you, @alvits. Yet will it has some side if I want to use Anaconda3 in my future projects? Can you provide more reference/keyword to anaconda mimicking `virtualenv`?

Comment: It depends on how the binaries in `anaconda3` is compiled. You may need to re-add the path to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` when using it. But I suggest trying it out without adding it first to see if it works.

Comment: @alvits Thank you. I will try your suggestion.

Answer (score 1):

Because /home/user/anaconda3/lib/libcrypto.so.1.0.0 is not the correct file required for ssh.

In your case, you should do:

1. `sudo ldconfig /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/`

   - you need to use the libcrypto.so from /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ as library path instead of the Anaconda lib.
2. `export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/home/user/anaconda3/lib/`

   - add a line in you environment config file, if you want to use Anaconda lib as a backup lib path.

Comment: thanks for this. For me solution was to setup LD_LIBRARY_PATH like so: export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/:$HOME/miniconda2/lib/